# Django class sql data pull

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have class:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ratingtype = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

that lets me display total amount of lines in database table with this tag:

```
{{post.likes.count}}
```

What would be the best way to modify this class so i can differentiate the counting by two ratingtype (1 or 0)

Comment: I think the best thing is to have a boolean, and that by default it is false, when it becomes positive a count is made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make queries in the template. Templates are used for *render* logic, not business logic.

You can annotate the `Post` object(s) you are fetching with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Post.objects.annotate(
    likes0=Count('likes', filter=Q(ratingtype=0)),
    likes1=Count('likes', filter=Q(ratingtype=1))
)
```

The `Product`s that arise from this queryset will have two extra attributes: `.likes0` and `.likes1` that contains the number of `likes` with `ratingtype=0` and `ratingtype=1` respectively. You thus can then render this with:

```
{{ post.likes0 }}
{{ post.likes1 }}
```